# HUD with multiple lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, hud

How can I make HUD that has multiple lines?
He is my code, but the labelText is one line

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[TTNavigator navigator] window] animated:YES];
HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.png"]];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"text1 \n text2";
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031656/1557383 u can try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use detailsLabelText method, i.e.

```
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"your next line here"
```

you can change the style using detailsLabelFont.

Comment: So clever! Solved my issue perfectly!

Comment: as of v1.0.0 (maybe even earlier) detailsLabelText is deprecated and you are advised to use detailsLabel.text

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way (expanding on Jon Madison's answer):

```
hud.labelText = @"Your first line of text is";
hud.detailsLabelText = @"followed by your next line of text";
hud.detailsLabelFont = hud.labelFont;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but you need to modify the `MBProgressHUD.m` file's code.

In `MBProgressHUD.m` file, there is a method `- (void)setupLabels`. In that method, a label is created. Make that label multiline label by setting its property `numberOfLines`.

Ex:

`label.numberOfLines = 2;`

Hope it works..

Comment: Are you sure about that function? I do not have it in `MBProgressHUD.m`

Comment: Ya I'm, sure... Its in MBProgressHUD.m file

Comment: The only deference is version. You are using 0.4

Comment: @Luda: try to find out a label that sets its text from `labelText` string variable...

Comment: I will download the newer version