# MBProgressHUD to show label text in more than one line

Tags: ios, label, newline, frame, mbprogresshud

Hi i have a MBProgressHUD on my iPad screen. Works perfectly fine. But i want to change the label to show in three lines.Like this

```
    self.hud =  [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];  
self.hud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 143);

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.hud];
self.hud.delegate = self;
self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
NSString *strloadingText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading Data.\r Please Wait.\r 1-2 Minutes"];
NSLog(@"the loading text will be %@",strloadingText);
self.hud.labelText = strloadingText;
[self.hud show:YES];
```

So i want the label in 3 lines

Loading Data.

Please Wait

1-2 Minutes

OR
can i assign an image to the HUD?

All this should be in the labeltext. But i am ending up with only one line. How can i do that?
If you need more info, please ask.Thanks.

Comment: Try with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading Data.\n Please Wait.\n 1-2 Minutes"]`. Not sure if it is handled in MBProgressHUD.

Comment: @ACB.I tried. Still in the same line.

Comment: Then you might have to modify the MBProgressHUD implementation. Check if there are any options available for this.

Comment: @ACB. Can i add imageview for MBProgressHUD?

Comment: You can create your own UIView which looks like MBProgressHUD. Basically you need to set the alpha, corner radius for layer etc.. and then add activity indicator and UILabel on that.

Comment: @ACB. I changed the detailsLabel.numberOfLines=3 in MBProgressHUD.m. And bingo it showed up in 3 lines. I changed the number of lines for labelText but it didnt work. So now i am setting up detailsLabelText as the required string.

Answer (score 35):

MBProgressHUD's detailsLabelText property is multiline but not labelText property.

So, you can try something like this

```
MBProgressHUD * hud =  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 143);

hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
NSString *strloadingText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading Data."];
NSString *strloadingText2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Please Wait.\r 1-2 Minutes"];

NSLog(@"the loading text will be %@",strloadingText);
hud.labelText = strloadingText;
hud.detailsLabelText=strloadingText2;
```

You can set detailsLabelText font by using the property detailsLabelFont.

Comment: That's interesting. Out of curiosity I looked through the source trying to figure out why detailsLabelText was multiline but labelText wasn't and couldn't see any difference. Do you know what parameter makes one multiline and the other not?

Comment: The parameter is numberOfLines. Set it like so: label.numberOfLines = 0;

Answer (score 5):

I had a question like this, too !

You can set `hud.label.numberOfLines = 0;`

And it works!

Answer (score 3):

The reason why labelText differs from detailsText, I imagine because it's meant to be a very similar to UIAlertView from the title/description perspective.

The differences between the two labels is quite distinct because of their purpose, for instance:

- Titles have bigger fonts, oft times bold in comparison to detail text.
- Titles are meant to be short and obvious, taken from a popular dictionary site (description speaks for itself):

> Title: A descriptive name; an epithet.

I'd recommend not having a multi-line title, keeping it short, and using the description text.

The reason why multi-line titles do not work is because of the layoutSubviews implementation, the size is not being calculated. if you inspect MBProgressHud.m, within layoutSubviews,

```
CGFloat remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin; 
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, remainingHeight);
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [detailsLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
totalSize.width = MAX(totalSize.width, detailsLabelSize.width);
totalSize.height += detailsLabelSize.height;
if (detailsLabelSize.height > 0.f && (indicatorF.size.height > 0.f || labelSize.height > 0.f)) {
    totalSize.height += kPadding;
}
```

Note the `-[NSString sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:]` call for the description text; this method calculates the size required to display the text - using as many lines as necessary, whereas the `-[NSString sizeWithFont:]` calculates the size required to display the text, but only up to displaying one line.

I would advise against having a multi-line title, and instead provide a shorter title, with some description text to accompany it.

If you simply must have the multi-line title (all changes within MBProgressHud.m):

```
- (void)setupLabels {
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.textAlignment = MBLabelAlignmentCenter;
label.opaque = NO;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = self.labelFont;
label.text = self.labelText;
>>> label.numberOfLines = 0;
[self addSubview:label];  
    ...
```

Replace:

```
CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
labelSize.width = MIN(labelSize.width, maxWidth);
totalSize.width = MAX(totalSize.width, labelSize.width);
totalSize.height += labelSize.height;
if (labelSize.height > 0.f && indicatorF.size.height > 0.f) {
    totalSize.height += kPadding;
}

CGFloat remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin; 
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, remainingHeight);
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [detailsLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

With:

```
CGFloat remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin;  
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, remainingHeight);  

CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
totalSize.width = MAX(totalSize.width, labelSize.width);
totalSize.height += labelSize.height;

if (labelSize.height > 0.f && indicatorF.size.height > 0.f) {
    totalSize.height += kPadding;
}

remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin;  
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [detailsLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Hope this isn't too late to help.

Answer (score 0):

self.hud.minSize = CGSizeMake(300, 100);